# fixed length Alphanumeric generation in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How to generate fixed length alpha-numeric strings in informatica?

output should look like:

```
STR001
STR002
STR003
STR004
.
.
```

.

Comment: the string part is fixed?

Comment: The STR part is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Sequence GEnerator` to generate the numbers. In `Expression Transformation` add any desired prefix. Use `LPad` or `RPad` function fill the value with characters of your choice up to the lenght you need.